# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 With GetToken

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-authenticator

I am trying to get the google account token for the already logged in account in my android device. But I am getting the Fatal Exception: AsyncTask#1 error and my application is getting creahsed.

Here I am attached my source code and error file.

Please kindly help.

Thank you.

```
public class Web_view_demo extends ActionBarActivity {

    ProgressBar progress;
    String mScope="oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN;;
    String accountName="";

    final Activity activity = this;
    private ProgressDialog dialog1;
    String token1="";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);



        Intent intent=getIntent();


        final String accountName = intent.getExtras().getString("accountName");

        Toast.makeText(this,"Account Selected="+accountName, 5000).show();

        new GetGoogleToken().execute();

         Toast.makeText(this,"Auth Token="+token1, 5000).show();

    }

    private class GetGoogleToken extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

        protected void onPreExecute() { 
            dialog1 = new ProgressDialog(Web_view_demo.this); // App - your main activity class
            dialog1.setMessage("Please wait...");
            dialog1.show();
            }   

        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            Log.i("Inside on AsynTask:","I am here");

            try {
                token1 = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Web_view_demo.this,
                     accountName,
                        mScope);
                Log.i("Inside on AsynTask:","I am here");
            } catch (IOException transientEx) {
                // Network or server error, try later
                Log.e("IO", transientEx.toString());
            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
                // Recover (with e.getIntent())
                Log.e("UserRecover", e.toString());
                //Intent recover = e.getIntent();
                //startActivityForResult(recover, 1);
            } catch (GoogleAuthException authEx) {
                // The call is not ever expected to succeed
                // assuming you have already verified that 
                // Google Play services is installed.
                Log.e("GoogleAuth", authEx.toString());
            }

            Log.i("Token:",token1);
            return token1;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            dialog1.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

---

```
08-04 14:34:55.705: E/AndroidRuntime(25473): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-04 14:34:55.705: E/AndroidRuntime(25473): Process: test.dsi.decathnavigation, PID: 25473
08-04 14:34:55.705: E/AndroidRuntime(25473): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-04 14:34:55.705: E/AndroidRuntime(25473):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
08-04 14:34:55.705: E/AndroidRuntime(25473):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
08-04 14:34:55.705: E/AndroidRuntime(25473):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
08-04 14:34:55.705: E/AndroidRuntime(25473):    at  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
08-04 14:34:55.705: E/AndroidRuntime(25473):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
08-04 14:34:55.705: E/AndroidRuntime(25473):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-04 14:34:55.705: E/AndroidRuntime(25473):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-04 14:34:55.705: E/AndroidRuntime(25473):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
08-04 14:34:55.705: E/AndroidRuntime(25473): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be empty: 
08-04 14:34:55.705: E/AndroidRuntime(25473):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1469)
08-04 14:34:55.705: E/AndroidRuntime(25473):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
08-04 14:34:55.705: E/AndroidRuntime(25473):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.s$a$a.a(Unknown Source)
08-04 14:34:55.705: E/AndroidRuntime(25473):    at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
08-04 14:34:55.705: E/AndroidRuntime(25473):    at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
08-04 14:34:55.705: E/AndroidRuntime(25473):    at test.dsi.decathnavigation.Web_view_demo$GetGoogleToken.doInBackground(Web_view_demo.java:117)
08-04 14:34:55.705: E/AndroidRuntime(25473):    at test.dsi.decathnavigation.Web_view_demo$GetGoogleToken.doInBackground(Web_view_demo.java:1)
08-04 14:34:55.705: E/AndroidRuntime(25473):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
08-04 14:34:55.705: E/AndroidRuntime(25473):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
08-04 14:34:55.705: E/AndroidRuntime(25473):    ... 4 more
08-04 14:34:56.274: E/WindowManager(25473): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity test.dsi.decathnavigation.Web_view_demo has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{420eb868 V.E..... R......D 0,0-513,144} that was originally added here
08-04 14:34:56.274: E/WindowManager(25473):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:359)
08-04 14:34:56.274: E/WindowManager(25473):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
08-04 14:34:56.274: E/WindowManager(25473):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
08-04 14:34:56.274: E/WindowManager(25473):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
08-04 14:34:56.274: E/WindowManager(25473):     at test.dsi.decathnavigation.Web_view_demo$GetGoogleToken.onPreExecute(Web_view_demo.java:109)
08-04 14:34:56.274: E/WindowManager(25473):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
08-04 14:34:56.274: E/WindowManager(25473):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
08-04 14:34:56.274: E/WindowManager(25473):     at test.dsi.decathnavigation.Web_view_demo.onCreate(Web_view_demo.java:58)
08-04 14:34:56.274: E/WindowManager(25473):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
08-04 14:34:56.274: E/WindowManager(25473):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
08-04 14:34:56.274: E/WindowManager(25473):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
08-04 14:34:56.274: E/WindowManager(25473):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
08-04 14:34:56.274: E/WindowManager(25473):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
08-04 14:34:56.274: E/WindowManager(25473):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
08-04 14:34:56.274: E/WindowManager(25473):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-04 14:34:56.274: E/WindowManager(25473):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-04 14:34:56.274: E/WindowManager(25473):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
08-04 14:34:56.274: E/WindowManager(25473):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 14:34:56.274: E/WindowManager(25473):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-04 14:34:56.274: E/WindowManager(25473):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
08-04 14:34:56.274: E/WindowManager(25473):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
08-04 14:34:56.274: E/WindowManager(25473):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Have you read the LogCat? The error is in it: "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be empty:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be
>   empty

Inside `AsyncTask` you use `accountName` variable:

```
token1 = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Web_view_demo.this, accountName, mScope);
```

But variable is an instance member of `Web_view_demo` class. It is set once to an empty string, and to nothing else later:

```
String accountName="";
```

And in `onCreate` method, when you do:

```
final String accountName = intent.getExtras().getString("accountName");
```

you don't set value to instance member variable named `accountName`, but **you create a new variable, visible only inside `onCreate` method**. If you wanted to set the instance member variable, then change previous line to:

```
accountName = intent.getExtras().getString("accountName");
```

Answer (score 0):

change :

```
  protected void onPostExecute(Void unused)
```

to

```
   protected void onPostExecute(String unused)
```